# How to store selected datepicker javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime, strtotime

I need help badly form my task.
When I had selected the date such as 2015-05-08 it stored as 1970-01-01.
I had tried all the solutions that I found but it still can't work well.

Below are my codes. Hope you guys can help. Appreciate it.

### **PHP files**

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "Page1">
    <div class="title">
      <h3>Check-in / Check-out Date</h3></div>
        <div class = "container">
            <div style="padding: 10px 50px 0 20px; ">
                        <table align="center" class="bookingForm" style="color: #000;">
                           <tr>
                            <td>Check-in date:</td>
                            <td><input id="cid" type="text"  name="cid" onchange="checkNight()"></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                            <td>Check-out date:</td>
                            <td><input id="cod" type="text"  name="cod" onchange="checkNight()"></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                            <td>No. of night:</td>
                            <td><input id="night" type="text" value="0" name="night"></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td></td>
                             <td><input type="button" value="Next" name="nextButton" id="nextButton" class="nextButton" onclick="next()" >
                                 <input type="hidden" id="noRoom" style="display:none;" value="1">
                             </td>
                           </tr>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cid").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function(date) {
                var date2 = $('#cid').datepicker('getDate');
                date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
                $('#cod').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
                checkNight();
            }
        });
        $('#cod').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            onClose: function() {
                    var dt1 = $('#cid').datepicker('getDate');
                    var dt2 = $('#cod').datepicker('getDate');
                    //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1
                    if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                        var minDate = $('#cod').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                        $('#cod').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                        checkNight();
                    }
                }
        });
    });

    function checkNight() {
        var dateGet = new Date;
        var dateGet2 = new Date;

        dateGet = $('#cid').datepicker("getDate");
        dateGet2 = $('#cod').datepicker("getDate");


        if ($('#cid').val() != "" && $('#cod').val() != "") {
           var diffDay = Math.abs(dateGet2 - dateGet);
           diffDay = diffDay / 86400000;
           if(diffDay<0){
            }else{
                document.getElementById('night').value = diffDay;
            }
          }
        }

    function next(){
        var cid = $("#cid").val();
        var cod = $("#cod").val();
        var night = $("#night").val();
        //if cid and cod are empty
        if(cid == "" || cod == ""){
            alert('Please key in the required field');
        }
        //redirect to next page if fuifil requirement
        else{
            window.location="http://localhost/reserve/app/room.php";
        }
    }
```

---

### **Storing Date Code**

```
<?php
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$cidDate = date('Ymd', strtotime($cid));    
$cod = $_POST['cod'];
$codDate = date('Ymd', strtotime($cod));
$night = $_POST['night'];

$sql = ("INSERT INTO `check`(`cid`, `cod`, `night`) VALUES ('$cidDate','$codDate','$night')");
```

?>
    ?>

Comment: And what you were getting within `$cid` and `$cod`. Can you post that too

Comment: you'd probably need to provide the format of your input date that you're using

Comment: For $cid I select 2015-05-08 and $cod I select 2015-05-10 then the night will automatically show 2.
But in database both cid and cod show 1970-01-01 and night is 0

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: @tadman do you mean sth like this:
$sql = ("INSERT INTO `check`(`cid`, `cod`, `night`) VALUES ('$cidDate','$codDate','$night')");

Comment: That's going to get you into huge trouble, yes. Don't do that. If you insist on using `mysql_query`, which is highly ill-advised, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string` on each value. PDO makes this much easier since your query looks like `INSERT INTO check (cid, cod, night) VALUES (:cid, :cod, :night)` and you can map the values using the [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) feature. Way cleaner, easier to read, and harder to get wrong.

Comment: @tadman well, im not quite sure how to use PDO code ><

Comment: It's not that hard. I linked to a simple tutorial there, plus the documentation. The differences between that and `mysql_query` relate mostly to connecting and how to add user data. The SQL itself is the same. If you want to get serious about PHP development, you might want to find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your style and needs as those can make you *considerably* more productive by providing a solid foundation you can build off of instead of having to write every last thing yourself.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the help. I think i need time to digest all the advices ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem few days ago.
Below are the codes where I used POST form to store the value
and the date I used preg_replace

---

```
<?php
        error_reporting(0);// Turn off all error reporting
        include('reserveDB.php');//pass the reserveDB.php
        if(!isset($_POST['dateButton'])) {
    ?>

    <body>
        <div id ="header">
            <img src="../images/welcome.jpg" alt="image" width="100%" height="50%">
        </div>
        <div id = "wrapper">
            <div id = "Page1">
                <div class="title">
                    <h3>Check-in / Check-out Date</h3></div>
                    <div class = "container">
                        <div style="padding: 10px 50px 0 20px; ">
                            <div id = "dateTable">
                            <form name="dateCheck" method="post">
                                <table cellpadding="10">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left"><div align="center"><a>Check-in date:</a></div></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><div align="center">
                                          <input type="textbox" id="cid" name="cid" onchange="summary()" style="width: 220px; text-align:center;" placeholder="Check-in"/>
                                        </div></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"> <div align="center"><a>Check-out date:</a></div></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><div align="center">
                                          <input type="textbox" id="cod" name="cod" onchange="summary()" style="width: 220px; text-align:center;"  placeholder="Check-out" />
                                        </div></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><div align="center"><a>Number of night:</a></div></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><div align="center">
                                          <input type="textbox" id="noOfDay" name="noOfDay" value="1"  style="width: 40px; text-align:center;" readonly/>
                                        </div></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"><div align="center">
                                          <input type="submit" name="dateButton" class="dateButton" value="Next"/>
                                        </div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                            <div id="reservationSummary">
                                <h3 align="center">SUMMARY</h3>
                                <div class="line" style="padding-top: 5px;"></div>
                                <div align="center">
                                  <table id="reservationInfo" >
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><a><b>Check-in Date:</b></a></td>
                                      <td style="width:100px;">
                                        <div id="summaryCID" name = "summaryCID" class="summaryCID" style="text-align:right;"></div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><a><b>Check-Out Date:</b></a></td>
                                      <td style="width:100px;">
                                        <div id="summaryCOD" name = "summaryCOD" class="summaryCOD" style="text-align:right;"></div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><a><b>Night(s):</b></a></td>
                                      <td style="width:100px;">
                                        <div id="summaryDay" name="summaryDay" class="summaryDay" style="text-align:right;"></div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>    
            </div> 
        </div>            
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    else{
        $cid = preg_replace("#(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})#", "$3-$1-$2", $_POST['cid']);
        $cid = mysql_real_escape_string($cid);
        $cod = preg_replace("#(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})#", "$3-$1-$2", $_POST['cod']);
        $cod = mysql_real_escape_string($cod);
        $night = $_POST['noOfDay'];
            if(($_POST['cid']=='') || ($_POST['cod'])==''){
                echo 'Please fill in the date<br><a href = "check.php">Back To Check Page</a>';
            }
            else{
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `checkdate`(`cid`, `cod`, `noOfDay`) VALUES ('$cid','$cod',$night)");
                Header("Refresh: 1; url = room.php?cid=".$cid."&cod=".$cod."&night=".$night."");
            }
    }
    ?>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way to do it.
You should use form in your html.
After that you can chose if you want to send variable through action attribute of your form
(ex: "`<form action="page.php" method="php">`)
or you can do that directly in jquery
(ex: `$('.nextButton).on("click", function(){

$.post( "page.php", { param1: "<Value1>", param2: "Value2" } );

});`

Comment: I had tried the form method but it stil failed.
As for jquery method
I had this code:

function next(){
  var cid = document.getElementById('cid').value;
        var cod = document.getElementById('cod').value;
        var night = document.getElementById('night').value;
  //if cid and cod are empty
  if(cid == "" || cod == ""){
         alert('Please key in the required field');
  }
  //redirect to next page if fuifil requirement
  else{
         window.location="http://localhost/reserve/app/room.php";
     }
 }

do you mean i need to add in the sql in this code?

Comment: Have a try changing window.location="http://localhost/reserve/app/room.php";  with $.post( "room.php", { cid: cid, cod: cod, night:night } ); And in mysql_query you shouldn't use $_POST['...'] but the variable name like $cid

Comment: I had changed the window.location to what you had adviced but it still cant work. As for mysql_query i had changed.

Comment: Try this $.post( "test.php", { cid: cid, cod: cod, night:night }, function(result){ $('body').html(result);}); this way you get the result from the room.php page, but how it is now you are not inserting anything. You can write if(mysqli_query(sql)){echo "Inserted successfull"; else echo "Insert failed";}

Comment: Did you set the db connection like this? 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "<your username>";
$password = "<your password>";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);  After that you should use $conn in you mysqli_query method like this mysqli_query($con, sql);

Comment: <?php

//connect with SQL
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if($con){
//check the connection and the database
 mysql_select_db('reserve',$con) or die('Database cannot select');
}

else{
//if not, then failed
 print 'Failed to connect';
}
?>

Comment: mysql and mysqli is the sme?
i though is different~
phpMyAdmin is mysql right?
or just the same?

Comment: Mysqli is the improved driver. i stands for improved, you should use this instead of mysql

Comment: owh~~~
cause my school focus on mysql ><

anyway, thanks for the help. Appreciate it.